# This gets an error even though it shouldn't

Tags: php

This errors:

```
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng("../Shop/" . $sql1->Eyes);
```

I don't know why? I get this error:

```
Warning: imagecreatefrompng(../Shop/none.png) [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/m4st3r/public_html/avatar.php on line 18
```

But there is a directory named Shop and there is a file named none.png?

Help?

Comment: Use an absolute path instead of a relative one - the Shop directory and `none.png` aren't in the place that your code is looking for them

Comment: Your script is not running from where you think it is. try `echo realpath("../Shop");` to see where that relative path really goes.

Comment: Take a look at [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and see the comments on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path, but be sure that the "Shop" directory is in the parent directory of the parent directory of the first called php file ("index.php" by instance).